# Inserting in MySQL replacing the contents using Pandas

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying the following:

```
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd
con = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}'.format(user,password,host,port,db))
df = pd.DataFrame({'pass':["11","44","33"],'trust':[1,2,3],'name' : ['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3']})
df.to_sql(con=con, name='check_data_5', if_exists='replace',index=False,method="multi")
```

The above code worked fine. and I got the following output:

```
name pass  trust
User 1  11  1
User 2  44  2
User 3  33  3
```

But when I tried to change data in the dataframe and insert the values into the MySQL I received a replaced output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pass':["2233","44","33"],'trust':[1,2,3],'name' : ['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3']})
df.to_sql(con=con, name='check_data_5', if_exists='replace',index=False,method="multi")
```

The output of the above statements are:

```
name pass  trust
    User 1  2233    1
    User 2  44  2
    User 3  33  3
```

Whereas I was expecting:

```
name pass  trust
    User 1  11  1
    User 1  2233    1
    User 2  44  2
    User 3  33  3
```

I though the problem is because I do not have a primary key in the table. So I create a table first and then execute the above sequence I received the same response. :
Created the table with the query:

```
create_table = 'create table `check_data_5` (`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin, `trust` int(1) NOT NULL, `pass` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL UNIQUE,PRIMARY KEY(`pass`) )AUTO_INCREMENT=1;'
```

Please let me know what I am missing in the process. I need to solve this. I guess the problem is with pandas. Using `Python 3.5.0`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you meant to make the `name` field the primary key, not `pass` ?

```
create_table = 'create table `check_data_5` (`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin, `trust` int(1) NOT NULL, `pass` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY(`name`) ) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;'
```

Comment: No this is not what I am trying to achieve. You see I have given the examples in full. What I expect is given in the question.Tell me, whether your solution will be helpful to accomplish it? I guess the answer is no.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you wanted to achieve. Maybe you did not want this? `if_exists='replace'`